# How can I instantiate an object of class Foo<T> for Ts listed in MyTypes in a test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googletest

I want to test a template class with gtest. I read about `TYPED_TEST`s in [Google Test manual](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#typed-tests) and looked at [official example](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/samples/sample6_unittest.cc) they reference, but still can't wrap my head around getting an object of template class instantiated in my test.

Suppose the following simple template class:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    T data ;
};
```

In testing class we declare

```
typedef ::testing::Types<int, float> MyTypes ;
```

Now how can I instantiate an object of class `Foo<T>` for `T`s listed in `MyTypes` in a test?

For example:

```
TYPED_TEST(TestFoo, test1)
{
    Foo<T> object ;
    object.data = 1.0 ;
    
    ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(object.data, 1.0) ;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inside a test, refer to the special name `TypeParam` to get the type parameter. So you could do

```
TYPED_TEST(TestFoo, test1)
{
    Foo<TypeParam> object ; // not Foo<T>
    object.data = 1.0 ;

    ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(object.data, 1.0) ;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot TemplateRex! I tried using TypeParam before, but my mistake was that I thought it's a class and did 

    `TypeParam n ; Foo<n> object ;` 

sort of thing, which of course didn't compile. Cheers!

Comment: @Puchatek Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 2):

Since I couldn't figure out on my own how to combine TemplateRex's answer with Puchatek's original snippet, here's a complete compilable example. I got this by reading [GTest's own comments](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/b007c54/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h#L39-L68), which are pretty helpful.

Put the following into `test.cpp`:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

using vector_typelist = testing::Types<char, int*, std::regex>;
template<class> struct vector_suite : testing::Test {};
TYPED_TEST_SUITE(vector_suite, vector_typelist);

TYPED_TEST(vector_suite, bigness)
{
    std::vector<TypeParam> v;
    EXPECT_TRUE(sizeof(v) >= sizeof(TypeParam));
}
```

Compile with the appropriate `-I` and `-l` options. This might look something like:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -I/usr/local/include test.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main
```

or (if you use `pkg-config`):

```
g++ -std=c++14 $(pkg-config --cflags gtest) test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs gtest_main)
```

Run the executable and you should see something like this:

```
$ ./a.out
Running main() from /foobar/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 3 tests from 3 test suites.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/0, where TypeParam = char
[ RUN      ] vector_suite/0.bigness
[       OK ] vector_suite/0.bigness (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/0 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/1, where TypeParam = int*
[ RUN      ] vector_suite/1.bigness
[       OK ] vector_suite/1.bigness (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/1 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/2, where TypeParam = std::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >
[ RUN      ] vector_suite/2.bigness
test.cpp:12: Failure
Value of: sizeof(v) >= sizeof(TypeParam)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] vector_suite/2.bigness, where TypeParam = std::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> > (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/2 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 3 tests from 3 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] vector_suite/2.bigness, where TypeParam = std::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >

 1 FAILED TEST
```

(I put in this failed test purely to demonstrate what happens when a typed test fails. In fact `sizeof(std::vector<std::regex>)` is indeed smaller than `sizeof(std::regex)`.)

---

Be aware that `TYPED_TEST` produces a family of test suites with related but non-identical names. There is no single `vector_suite` anymore:

```
$ ./a.out --gtest_filter=vector_suite.*
Running main() from /foobar/gtest_main.cc
Note: Google Test filter = vector_suite.*
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test suites.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

Instead there are `vector_suite/0`, `vector_suite/1`, and `vector_suite/2`:

```
$ ./a.out --gtest_filter=vector_suite/0.*
Running main() from /foobar/gtest_main.cc
Note: Google Test filter = vector_suite/0.*
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/0, where TypeParam = char
[ RUN      ] vector_suite/0.bigness
[       OK ] vector_suite/0.bigness (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from vector_suite/0 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```