# How to test C++ template class with multiple template parameters with GTest?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a small class:

```
template <class key_t, class value_t>
class node_t {
public:
    node_t();
    void set_key(key_t);
    key_t get_key();
    void set_value(value_t);
    value_t get_value();

private:
    key_t key;
    value_t value;
};

template <class key_t, class value_t>
node_t<key_t, value_t>::node_t() {
    key = (key_t)0;
    value = (value_t)0;
}

template <class key_t, class value_t>
void node_t<key_t, value_t>::set_key(key_t key) {
    this->key = key;
}

template <class key_t, class value_t>
key_t node_t<key_t, value_t>::get_key() {
    return this->key;
}

template <class key_t, class value_t>
void node_t<key_t, value_t>::set_value(value_t value) {
    this->value = value;
}

template <class key_t, class value_t>
value_t node_t<key_t, value_t>::get_value() {
    return this->value;
}
```

How I can test it with Google Testing framework?

```
/*
TEST(node_test_t, node_test) {
    node_t<std::string, float> node;

    std::string key = node.get_key();
    ASSERT_STREQ(key, 0);

    node.set_key("one");
    ASSERT_STREQ(node.get_key(), "one");

    float value = node.get_value();
    ASSERT_EQ(value, 0);

    node.set_value(2.4);
    ASSERT_EQ(node.get_value(), 2.4);
}
*/

// Updated
TEST(node_test_t, node_test)
{
    node_t<std::string, float> node;

    std::string key = node.get_key();
    ASSERT_STREQ("0", key.c_str());

    node.set_key("one");
    ASSERT_STREQ("one", node.get_key().c_str());

    float value = node.get_value();
    ASSERT_EQ(value, 0);

    node.set_value(2.4f);
    ASSERT_EQ(node.get_value(), 2.4f);
}
```

I found also:

- [How to test c++ template class with multiple template parameters using gtest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382157/how-to-test-c-template-class-with-multiple-template-parameters-using-gtest)
- [gtest - testing template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079702/gtest-testing-template-class)
- https://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/sample6_unittest.cc

  But I was not able to compile the result. Please show a simple example how I can write tests for this class using Google Testing Framework.

UPD: I also tried this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/googletestframework/class$20template/googletestframework/wSlsjwU7vls/9ulYoFliuLgJ

```
template <class key_t, class value_t>
class node_testing_t : public node_t<key_t, value_t> {
public:
    using node_t<key_t, value_t>::get_value;
};

TEST(node_test_case, get_value) {
    node_testing_t<std::string, float> node_testing;
    ASSERT_EQ(0, node_testing.get_value());
}
```

and I also have `LNK2019` error:

```
1>------ Skipped Build: Project: RUN_TESTS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>------ Build started: Project: googlemock, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>node_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall node_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>::node_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>(void)" (??0?$node_t@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall node_testing_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>::node_testing_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>(void)" (??0?$node_testing_t@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@@QAE@XZ)
3>node_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall node_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>::~node_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>(void)" (??1?$node_t@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall node_testing_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>::~node_testing_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>(void)" (??1?$node_testing_t@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@@QAE@XZ)
3>node_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall node_t<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float>::get_value(void)" (?get_value@?$node_t@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall node_test_case_get_value_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@node_test_case_get_value_Test@@EAEXXZ)
3>C:\Users\user\Desktop\hill-climbing\bin\tests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
4>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 2 skipped ==========
```

Comment: why need `delete`? `node_t<key_t, value_t>::~node_t() {
    delete key;
    delete value;
}`. You never alloc memory, so you don't need `delete`.

Comment: @BlackMamba thank you, fixed

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the full compilation error output.

Comment: @AntonioPérez I added compilation error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example on linux with gcc 4.8.4 and it has no problem to link, although the test execution fails because an exception is thrown upon `node` object construction since the line `key = (key_t)0` in the constructor tries to cast a `0` into a `std::string` object.

That said, in your case, the MSVC linker complains that in the `node_test.obj` file there are unresolved references to symbols related to `node_t<std::string, float>`, namely constructor, destructor and get_value() member functions. Just the ones in use in your test.

You are instantiating the template within the scope of the test case, try to do it in the outer scope.

```
using node_string_float_t = node_t<std::string, float>;

TEST(node_test_t, node_test)
{
    node_string_float_t node;

    std::string key = node.get_key();
    ASSERT_STREQ("0", key.c_str());

    node.set_key("one");
    ASSERT_STREQ("one", node.get_key().c_str());

    float value = node.get_value();
    ASSERT_EQ(value, 0);

    node.set_value(2.4f);
    ASSERT_EQ(node.get_value(), 2.4f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read `ASSERT_STREQ` documentation? This macro accepts two `C-strings`, and you're attempting to pass it `std::string` and `int` in first, and `std::string` and `C-string` in second case. Btw, first argument is expected value and second one is actual, so you may want to switch the order in which you're providing parameters.

```
TEST(node_test_t, node_test)
{
    node_t<std::string, float> node;

    std::string key = node.get_key();
    ASSERT_STREQ("0", key.c_str());

    node.set_key("one");
    ASSERT_STREQ("one", node.get_key().c_str());

    float value = node.get_value();
    ASSERT_EQ(value, 0);

    node.set_value(2.4f);
    ASSERT_EQ(node.get_value(), 2.4f);
}
```

**P.S.** If you want to compare `std::string` objects you can use `EXPECT_EQ`, `EXPECT_NE` and so on.