# Obtain TypeParam() inside the TYPED_TEST

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googletest

I have a templated class that takes `data type T` and `size_t size` as templated arguments and wrote some unit-test to client class. I am repeating the same type of code at two different places one at the fixture and the other at TYPED_TEST in order to get the typed parameters.

In Fixture

```
  using T = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, Tup>;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, Tup>::value;
  using ClientT = typename Client<T, size>::ClientT;  // ClientT = std::array<T, size>
```

In TYPED_TEST - ReturnTrueWhenComparedWithSameClientID

```
  using T = typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(TypeParam())>::type;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(TypeParam())>::value;
  using ClientT = typename Client<T, size>::ClientT;  // std::array
```

Client

```
template <typename T, size_t size>
class Client {
 public:
  using ClientT = std::array<T, size>;

  Client(const ClientT& ID) : ID(ID) {}
  Client(const ClientT&& ID) : ID(std::move(ID)) {}

  inline const ClientT& getID() const { return ID; }
  inline bool isID(const ClientT& anotherID) const { return ID == anotherID; }

  inline bool operator==(const Client& anotherClient) { return ID == anotherClient.getID(); }

 private:
  ClientT ID;
};
```

And the unit test file looks like this

```
template <typename Tup>
class ClientTest : public testing::Test {
  using T = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, Tup>;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, Tup>::value;
  using ClientT = typename Client<T, size>::ClientT;  // ClientT = std::array<T, size>

 protected:
  ClientTest() : id(ClientT{1}), client(std::make_unique<Client<T, size>>(id)) {}
  ~ClientTest() override {}

  void setClient(const ClientT& id) { client.reset(new Client<T, size>(id)); }

  ClientT id;
  std::unique_ptr<Client<T, size>> client;
};

typedef testing::Types<std::tuple<std::int8_t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 16>>,
                       std::tuple<std::uint8_t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 24>>>
    Implementations;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(ClientTest, Implementations);

TYPED_TEST(ClientTest, ReturnTrueWhenComparedWithSameClientID) {
  using T = typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(TypeParam())>::type;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(TypeParam())>::value;
  using ClientT = typename Client<T, size>::ClientT;  // std::array

  ClientT new_id{15};
  this->setClient(new_id);
  EXPECT_EQ(this->client->getID(), new_id);
  EXPECT_TRUE(this->client->isID(new_id));
}
```

so far that tests are compiling and looking good. But I am not happy with repeating the same code block twice

I am wondering if there is a way that we can inherit the data type and size from the fixture into the TYPED_TEST or some thing better than already exsisting.

Thank you

Comment: This might be helpful, and also so that SO will create a link between the issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079702/gtest-testing-template-class/71926564#71926564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After referring to the [documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#typed-tests) from gtest

The type alias (using or typedef) are made public in TestFixture

```
template <typename Tup>
class ClientTest : public testing::Test {
public:
  using T = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, Tup>;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, Tup>::value;
  using ClientT = typename Client<T, size>::ClientT;  // ClientT = std::array<T, size>

 protected:
  ClientTest() : id(ClientT{1}), client(std::make_unique<Client<T, size>>(id)) {}
  ~ClientTest() override {}

  void setClient(const ClientT& id) { client.reset(new Client<T, size>(id)); }

  ClientT id;
  std::unique_ptr<Client<T, size>> client;
};
```

In the TYPED_TEST. the type alias (using or typedef) are resolved from TestFixture scope (TestFixture::)

```
TYPED_TEST(ClientTest, ReturnTrueWhenComparedWithSameClientID) {
  typename TestFixture::ClientT id{15};
}
```

Comment: Seems you can leave the aliases actually `protected` or `private` and still be able to access them with `TestFixture::`.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is **make the alias `ClientT` inside the fixture `ClientTest` `public`**

```
template <typename Tup>
class ClientTest : public testing::Test {
  public:
    using T = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, Tup>;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_element_t<1, Tup>::value;
    using ClientT = typename Client<T, size>::ClientT;
  protected:
    // ...
};
```

and then inside the `TYPED_TEST` access it either through `ClientTest<Tup>::ClientT` (where the template parameter `Tup` is given by `TypeParam()`)

```
using ClientT = typename ClientTest<decltype(TypeParam())>::ClientT;
```

or getting the **templated class type from the `this` pointer** as follows:

```
using ClientT = typename std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>::ClientT
```

If you only need it once like in your code above you might even only use

```
typename std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>::ClientT new_id{15};
```

Comment: Hi @2b-t , I went through some documentation from gtest and found a better way of resolving the scope

Comment: @BhanuKiran Oh, I was not aware of that! Thanks!